# How to get oauth_signature and oauth_nonce values for 'authorization' header in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to get oauth_signature and oauth_nonce values for 'authorization' header for couple of requests in a functional flow in Jmeter.

Flow:
1. Login using user/pwd (JSON format)>able to login using Jmeter and the response would have sessionid which is been used as cookie in subsequent requests
2. The cookie value is succsfully getting passed (HTTP cookie manager is already added)
3. After login Dashboard page opens which requires sessionid, this also works fine as cookie is getting passed
4. Logged in user will perform 'add' and 'submit' actions which has 'Authorization' header and the value of authorization header shows as below:
OAuth realm="xyz",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_consumer_key="testapp",oauth_timestamp="1517940303",oauth_nonce="abcd",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="uxO7B%2B%2Fbo%3D"

When recorded the flow using Blazemeter, captured above authorization header and observed this 'nonce' and 'signature' values been changed for subsequent requests dynamically.

Please guide how to have these dynamically changing values captured through co-relation or any other way to make test plan run successfully always.

Currently, when run the test-it fails wherever this 'authorization' header is passed.

Tried with HTTP authorization manager however not sure what be passed as user name/pwd since the login is success with the first request without HTTP authorization manager.

When tried to get details about how the signature values are getting generated, got below update:
Using oauth.js to generate signature .this is vendor file. But in the back end they are verifying signature and along with nonce and timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

`nonce` is basically a [**number used once**](https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/16/oauth-timestamps-and-nonces/) so you can send any unique number for this. In the majority of cases it is current timestamp in milliseconds from the beginning of Unix epoch - what JMeter's [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) produces so it is pretty simple.

With regards to signature it is a little bit more complex as you need to:

1. Get request method and URL
2. Get request parameters
3. Percent encode every key and value that will be signed
4. Sort the list of parameters alphabetically by encoded key
5. For each key/value pair of the request parameters:

   - Append the encoded key to the output string
   - Append the `=` character to the output string
   - Append the encoded value to the output string.
   - Append `&` sign between key/value pairs if your request has > 1 parameter
6. Use consumer secret, oauth token secret and encrypt the request using the algorithms your server expects.

Check out [OAuth Core 1.0 Revision A](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) article for more information regarding OAuth flow, hopefully it will shed some light on what needs to be done in order to perform authenticated requests. You may also find [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) useful.